# Como implantar uma aplicação no tomcat internamente em conjunto com outra externa?

Tags: servidor, tomcat

Tenho uma aplicação externa com acesso publico dentro do tomcat,
Um modulo chamado JSPUI, que é apontado para contexto root.xml.

E tenho outros dois módulos chamados SOLR e XMLUI, como faço para subir estes dois módulos somente para acesso interno e o modulo JSPUI para acesso publico em conjunto no mesmo tomcat?

Resumindo, como eu faço para cada aplicação específica dentro do tomcat seja visível internamente (a organização) e externamente (ao publico) em conjunto dentro do mesmo